# Sum two Values and Display as one (MySQL + PHP)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm looping a MySQL query to receive some data. I would like to count

```
PV001 + PV002 = $Value
```

just inside the MySQL Query and display always these two values summed as one. And this in a loop.

So I want:

```
<br>
Sum(ID1 + ID2)<br>
Sum(ID4 + ID6)<br>
Sum(ID7 + ID8)
```

... going on..

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| Name  | Count |  ID    |
+-------+-------+--------+
| PV001 |     2 |    1   |
| PV002 |     4 |    2   |
| PV004 |     5 |    3   |
| PV001 |     3 |    4   |
| PV003 |     4 |    5   |
| PV002 |     3 |    6   |
| PV001 |     6 |    7   |
| PV002 |     1 |    8   |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Are PV001 and PV002 always in matched pairs? Do we always match the the PV001 entry with the next sequential PV002 id?

Comment: Then you need to specify more clearly what the rules are for matching them and what to do with the unmatched ones.

Comment: ID1 + ID2 and why: ID4 + ID6 why not ID3 + ID4?